# Remove same values repeating in a row and convert into single value in pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset with multiple values repeating in the same row.Here is how the data looks.

```
id datapoint11     datapoint12    datapoint21    datapoint22
1  example.com    example2.com  example.com   example.com
2. test.com       test.com      test2.com      test.com
3. ex.com         ex.com        ex1.com       ex.com
4. te.com         test.com      te.com       test.com
```

I have eliminate the duplicate values treating (datapoint11,datapoint12) as one set and (datapoint21,datapoint22) as another set and replace them with null for each id.
Here is how the output should look like:

```
id datapoint11    datapoint12  datapoint21    datapoint22
1  example.com    example2.com  example.com   nan
2. test.com       nan           test2.com     test.com
3. ex.com         nan           ex1.com       ex.com
4. te.com         test.com      te.com       test.com
```

Code should be in python

This needs a subset dedupe instead of total dataframe dedupe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
df.where(df.apply(lambda x: ~x.duplicated(),axis=1),np.nan)
```

---

```
    id   datapoint1    datapoint2 datapoint3    datapoint4
0  1.0  example.com  example2.com        NaN  example3.com
1  2.0     test.com           NaN        NaN           NaN
2  3.0       ex.com           NaN    ex1.com           NaN
3  4.0       te.com      test.com        NaN           NaN
```

Comment: @anky_91 can i add subset to the duplicated function?  i have another 5 columns, which i dont want to include in the selection. I am getting unknown keyword error if subset is used

Comment: @shashank just pull those 5 columns out and concat them later over axis=1